# What is the use of the wp_links table?

Tags: custom-post-types, links

I'm wondering what is the use of the wp_links table, couldn't links have been implemented as a custom post type, if the menu system also uses custom post types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short **YES**, they could have. As anything else could have been implemented as custom post type and/or custom taxonomy.

But WordPress is a grown system - now 9 years old - and things are moving slowly to keep most stuff backwards compatible.

In short, with WP 3.5, the [Links Manager](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307) will be moved to a plugin, as you can read in the trac ticket.